How to read the contents of a .zip file with VBScript without actually extracting the files, and output file names to CSV?
Very new to VB. I have this code that echos the name of the files in a zip folder, but how do I modify this to save the results into a CSV?
Dim objSA, objSource, item

Set objSA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objSource = objSA.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).Items ()

For Each item in objSource
    WScript.Echo item
Next


Open a new text file and write the data line by line. ChatGPT will give you all the details.

Here's how you would send the results to a text file:
Dim objSA, objSource, item, fso, outputFile, pathToZipFile

pathToZipFile = "zip file path goes here"

Set objSA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Replace "output.csv" with your desired output file path
Set outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)

Set objSource = objSA.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).Items()

For Each item in objSource
    outputFile.WriteLine item
Next

outputFile.Close

Note: The question specified CSV, but the output is just a single column list of file or folder names from the root of the zip file, so there's no need for a CSV. The output file name can be changed from a TXT to a CSV extension, but that will make no difference to the contents.

This is such a basic question that there must be a duplicate already, but everything I found (so far) was more complicated.

This is creating and outputting the file but is not generating it in a CSV file format, you need to delimit the lines.

@user692942 The output is a single column file list, so there's nothing to delimit. I suppose it would be better if both the question and answer just said "text file".
